# how to avoid double data submission in struts1.1

Tags: javascript, struts

I am using dynaactionform in struts, I have problem related to same data submitted two times, I have one JSP page ,work of that jsp page is to search data and shows the search result in the same page. Its doing the search operation  based on the drop-down box provided in that JSP page , while click the button immediately two times same data is being retried and displaying in JSP page.

Action forward  forwarding the search result to JSP

I tried with `savetoken()` but I got problem as my page is loading once .

Is their any way to provide client side validation for this?

Is their any suggestion or way to solve this?

Comment: does your submit button has js event handler? or the form perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable the button before it retrieves data and finish displaying by JavaScript.

Here is one example:

```
<script>
function doSubmit() {
  document.getElementById("btnSubmit").setAttribute("disabled","disabled");
  return true;
}
</script>

<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" onclick="doSubmit()" value="Search" />
```

Comment: i tried this but button not submitting data to server only button is being disabled

Comment: Make sure:1) the button is included in `<form>`. 2) Your `<form>` has `action` value set. Another way is submit form by yourself, just put `document.getElementById("myFormId").submit();` in doSubmit().